# Axis 1.4 log4j-1.2.8.jar incompatible with XPages?

Tags: java, xpages, axis, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm trying to add some of the JARs from Apache Axis 1.4 into the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` directory. One of the JARs is `log4j-1.2.8.jar`.

As soon as this JAR is added to the lib directory, all XPages in the NSF stop working. I just get an error 500 with the following message:

> "HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception".

The following message is written to the error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
.    
.    
.    
.    
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:102)
```

[Link to full stack trace](http://juno.qchi.co.uk/log4j-xpages-error-130130.txt)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edited**

The AXIS jars are included in Domino install because Domino Web Services use them. That's why there is a conflict if you include them also.

I would recommend using JAX-WS which is newer than Axis. [Here is how to use it for Web Service client](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=8BCB11252D985E5885257AAF0016BC5A#7FB2E32EDB655B9985257AB800600B97). No need to add any JARs. You could also use JAX-WS *wsdl2java* instead of Apache one.

These two permissions need to be granted in *java.policy* file for this to work:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
```

Note that any kind of server update (f.e. fixpack install) will reset the java.policy file to default.

Comment: Another option is to use the built in Web Services functionality in an agent and then call that agent within an XPage.

Comment: Thanks Panu and Simon. I'm looking at JAX-WS via CXF as detailed on Stephan Wissel's site: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SUKV5

Comment: OK thanks for the pointers, I think I'm almost there. Created the stub classes using wsdl2java from CXF. Created JAR out of the stubs and imported into WEB-INF/lib within my nsf. Updated my code (stored in Java design elements) to use the new classes. Now trying to make the web service call from my XPage and am getting an AccessControlException: HTTP JVM: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission setContextClassLoader). Presumably I need to update a security setting somewhere to allow the request to be made?

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to grant java some more access.

Comment: Thanks Panu. I've added your suggestions to the java.policy file (and restarted http) but I'm still getting the same errors. I've added the permissions as follows: grant codeBase "xspnsf://server:0/path/to/myapp.nsf/-" { permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
 permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks"; }

Comment: @qchi Try first without limiting it to your .nsf. When you get that working you can experiment with limiting.