# Using External jar causing Error

Tags: jar, xpages

I'm doing the following steps:

1. Create an empty Notes Database (Lotus Notes 9.0.1 on Domino 9 Server)
2. Creating Xpage with only one Label
3. Inserting external Jar File (Code - Jars)

I tested this setting with different jar Files. In most cases there are no problems but I found 2 jar Files which produce an error 500 in XPage **without being referenced**

starface-rpc-1.6.442.jar

log4j-1.2.17.jar

Does someone has an idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Check the XPages log file for detailed error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two .jar files depend probably from other .jar files.

Look at the project pages like [this for log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/dependencies.html) to find out which .jar files you need to add to your application too.

***Update:***

Those .jar files stay in conflict with existing Java APIs used by Domino Server. That's why you get the error even without using them in an XPage as they get used by Domino Server executing an XPage.

Look here for [explanation the log4j issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606364/axis-1-4-log4j-1-2-8-jar-incompatible-with-xpages)

Comment: But why  is this a problem for XPages which don't use the external jar files? Does domino server load the jars on every run of Xpages?

Comment: If you put log4j into jar folder you get the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger" - there might be a conflict with standard Xpages logging...

Comment: What can I do? Is there an ability to use these jar?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get the .jars run in XPages environment. But, it would work for a Java agent. I just put all .jars (http://www.everythingaboutit.eu/2013/06/download-and-configure-starface-uci.html) into an agent and it seems to work there. Is that an option for you?

Comment: I try to use an Java Agent. Thanks