# How do you import the log4j jar file into an NSF?

Tags: xpages

I wanted to use the `Apache POI` classes for `Streaming Excel` spreadsheets. If I import the `log4j-1.2.17.jar` file into my Jars in the `nsf` then no `XPages` will load.

If I don't I get an error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;
> 	at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:45)
> 	at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
> 	at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:201)
> 	at

Since many third party `Java` apis seem to use the `log4j` is there a solution? I think this is the same issue that came up with the web services API in XPages?

Comment: log4j is part of the Domino already

Answer (score 1):

Your best course of action is to deploy OpenNTF essentials. It contains the POI classes and quite some ready made wrappers to make your life easier. 
Deploy into sever via update site nsf approach and deploy to your designer too

Comment: Hi Stephan, that does not work. There is no issue with the log4j but it appears that the Java code for the SXSSFWorkbook still needs a higher level of security to run.

Comment: Did you use the Poi4Xpages project (part of OpenNTF essentials)? They moved the POI classes into a plugin, so all rights are sorted out. You would not need to add any libs to your NSF

Comment: Yes, of course...Christian and I have been corresponding.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your error can be from the same reason than in that questions. It's a problem of standard jars which come along with the domino installation.

[Using External jar causing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730515/using-external-jar-causing-error)

[Axis 1.4 log4j-1.2.8.jar incompatible with XPages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606364/axis-1-4-log4j-1-2-8-jar-incompatible-with-xpages)

Comment: Yes, looking for a solution. IE, why, if the log4j is part of the Domino install, do I need to import this jar? Shouldn't my code just find it?

Answer (score 0):

Howard, put the jar file on the server as well as your local notes client and open up Java security permissions, I think that should do it. Also check that the version you are importing is compatible with Java version on Domino.