# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger in XPages

Tags: java, log4j, xpages, quartz-scheduler, lotus-notes

In our XPages project now we have to use Quartz Scheduler. I've tried to import all necessary jars which includes the following:

- c3p0-0.9.5.2
- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- quartz-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- quartz-jobs-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar

I've imported all the jars to our project but when loading a page (which doesn't even call quartz or anything) I get the following exception:

```
Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception
```

In a log I see:

```
01.12.19 2:04: Exception Thrown
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:473)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.initModule(NSFComponentModule.java:498)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.createNSFModule(NSFService.java:752)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.loadModule(NSFService.java:735)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:588)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(CLBootStrap.java:89)
    at com.ibm.xsp.config.BootStrap.init(BootStrap.java:82)
    at com.ibm.xsp.config.ConfigureCoreListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureCoreListener.java:39)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:465)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.<init>(Digester.java:346)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.digester(ConfigureListener.java:1005)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:383)
    at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(CLBootStrap.java:81)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1791.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:525)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:102)
    ... 21 more
```

I suspect that this problem is related to [Axis 1.4 log4j-1.2.8.jar incompatible with XPages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606364/axis-1-4-log4j-1-2-8-jar-incompatible-with-xpages)

I've tried to follow the advice and added the following to `java.policy` (section grant codeBase):

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
```

But still with no luck.

What's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to add your source code here, otherwise it is guesswork. Is it in SSJS (bad) or a JavaBean or an OSGi plugin?

Comment: You also will learn (potentially the hard way) that a process that’s running in the http stack eventually will time out. When you need a scheduler, you are firmly in plugin Land (and Threads)

Comment: Hello, I've resolved the issue by adding all logging libraries to lib/ext/. Have another problem though. Quartz doesn't seem to execute scheduled jobs :(

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue by adding all logging libraries:

- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar

to lib/ext

Comment: Don't add libraries to `lib/ext`. It is a great way to break applications that depend on a different version of a library. In addition, this functionality has been removed in recent Java versions. The proper solution would be to add it correctly to the classpath of your application.

Comment: I've tried to do so, reimported it like 3 times, but stull with no luck. The problem might be that my main template (with the libraries above) is used in child templates, maybe not everything is imported correctly, but as far as I can check everything is fine there

Comment: When I remember correctly, the problem that log4j isn't working within an NSF is the special classloader which is used to load resources within an NSF. If you want to use Quartz, you should create an OSGi plugin as Stephan recommended. Maybe you should take a look into OpenNTF OSGI Tasklet Service Project or otherwise Xots of the OpenNTF Domino API Project.